# Corda plugins and base-directory configuration

Tags: corda

I've setup a 4 node corda network with Notary, NodeA, NodeB and NodeC. When I bring up node and webserver instances for individual nodes, network comes up healthy. But,

1) I want to keep the configs under /etc/node.conf and runtime environment under /opt/corda directories for each of the nodes. When I provide --config-file and --base-directory arguments, per [documentation](https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html), corda refuses to run with both arguments as inputs. Is there a way to isolate runtime environments and configs?

2) How do I make the nodes pick up the jars under plugins ? I've created a plugins directory for each of these nodes under basedirectory path - /opt/corda/plugins. But, created it's own plugins directory. (Albeit, in my current setup I have a node.conf file under /opt/corda/ to keep it going). Where must I deploy my cordapps if corda is not picking up from the plugins folder I've created? Am I missing something here ? I've followed the [docs](https://docs.corda.net/deploying-a-node.html) during my setup.

Comment: A couple of questions. Is each node on a separate machine? And where is the node creating its plugins folder by default (you say it's not using /opt/corda/plugins)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As you observed, using the `--config-file` and `--base-directory` command line arguments together is currently disallowed.

However, you can store your `node.conf` file in a separate location by creating a symlink in the root of the node folder that points to the actual location of the `node.conf` file (e.g. `ln -s ./conf/node.conf ./node.conf` on Mac if you are storing the `node.conf` file in a `conf` folder in the node's root directory).

2) Awaiting clarification.